# Getting "(Unsupported) RunInstances operation, when trying to create AWS instances using boto3/python3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

When trying to create AWS instances using boto3/python3, i get the following error.

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (Unsupported) when calling the RunInstances operation: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations."
```

I can list already running instances, see code below

I get the same error, when i run the "ec2.create_instances" from ipython3, same error when removing the KeyName and InstanceType. There is no problem in creating instances from the web interface.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def list_instances():
 for instance in ec2.instances.all():
    #print (instance.tags)
    for tag in instance.tags:
           print(tag['Value'])

def create_instance():
    ec2.create_instances(
        ImageId='ami-00ee68f73a01ff18d',
        MinCount=1,
        MaxCount=1,
        KeyName='FPCcompute',
        InstanceType='t2.micro')

list_instances()
create_instance()
list_instances()
```

I would expect it to create an instance for me, but i just get this error that does not really give any good pointers to what is wrong. I can list the currently running instances, so that indicates to me that my credentials are set up correctly

```
Golden Compute Node
Master Node
Fryns

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_343/venv/manage_instance.py", line 19, in <module>
    create_instance()
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_343/venv/manage_instance.py", line 15, in create_instance
    KeyName='FPCcompute')#,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (Unsupported) when calling the RunInstances operation: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if, for example,  VPC the instances are supposed to be launched into supports the instance type.

Boto3 assumes some parameters if not explicitly provided, so it may be VPC settings, AZ, region or other resource configuration limitations which can affect this launch. Try specifying all of these explicitly identical to settings you use in web console (see [boto3 doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances))

Answer (score 1):

Thank you,
turns out that the problem was me trying to request a t2.micro instance, but that instance type might not exist in eu-north-1. When i changed the requested type to t3.micro i can now launch the machines